# Max number of devices to send to APNS socket sever

Tags: notifications, push, apple-push-notifications

Our push notification script that has worked for almost a year has suddenly stopped working. The script does the following:

1. Queries a DB for a list of iPhone device tokens
2. Opens an SSL socket connection to Apple's live APNS server

   ```
   $ctx = stream_context_create();
   stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
   stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);
   $fp = stream_socket_client($apnsHost, $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
   ```
3. creates a payload with a 255 byte sized message

   ```
   $payload = '{
     "aps": {
        "alert": "' . $message . '",
        "badge": 1,
        "sound": "default"
     }
   }';
   ```
4. Loops through each device and writes the payload to the open connection.

   ```
   $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
   fwrite($fp, $msg);
   ```
5. The connection is then closed.

   ```
   fclose($fp);
   ```

So my question is this-- nothing in the script has changed, but what HAS changed is the size of the database. I created a web interface that allows a user to send a payload to all iphone devices and when it runs it only takes a few seconds to send/load. Is it possible though that the number of devices in the DB (around 3500) is creating the problem?

What is the maximum number of devices that I can I send a push notification to when I write to the socket? Does a max or limit exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem wasn't the number of devices to sent to APNS. The problem turned out to be that Apple changed their API. You now need to check every single device to see if it's still valid (ie. if they are denying push notificaitons,  if the device deleted the app, etc.). If the device no longer accepts push notifications from your app and you send one to it anyways, Apple immediately drops the connection to your APNS socket. I now have a cronjob that runs a program once a day that checks and deletes any devices from my database that no longer accept push notifications (Apple has this list). But be careful -- once you pull the list of disabled device ids from Apple, Apple deletes it from their server and you can **never** pull it again.

You also need to update your push notification code to check if the connection is ever dropped. When the connection is dropped, the program needs to reestablish the connection and try to push again.

Comment: while testing in development mode,  I created 5 fake token UDIDs and placed a real one at the end then did what the OP did (set up a loop) to test basically what would happen if there was a problem with the first few,  this failed (or I have some other bug) on the first try, (never got the notification on the real device).   to test further  I sent the real one first and then the 5 fake ones in a loop.  this succeeds.     this seems inherently bad way to handle a first sent UDID?

Comment: that means if someone wipes their device and it's token number is in the middle of your group of sent devices, that your notifications are not delivered, and you have no idea if they ever got through.. could someone confirm this "experiment", I could also have some sort of length of message bug that causes this behavior. would be great to know if this is what Apple intends.

Comment: Not sure how it was in 2012, but currently the connection is not dropped once the device cannot accept the notification (e.g., due to the app being removed). I can hardly imagine, that such behaviour was even possible, since it will make APNS unusable - apps get constantly deleted from devices.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, based on experience, it seems that connections to APNS will fail after some number of notifications have been pushed through it.  In our own APNS library (http://code.google.com/p/javapns/), the multithreaded transmission engine included in the library automatically restarts connections after pushing 200 notifications (seems to be a magic number after trial and error).  Since we introduced that feature (along with some other minor comlink recovery options), the failed notification rate for large amounts of notifications went to zero.

Comment: There is no limit that I am aware of. It's definitely not 200 notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.. 
It looks like a limit of 2000 devices is the maximum.
So, 2000 (or less) tokens by socket opened. Try and see !

Comment: Are sure its 2000 and not 200?

Comment: Worth reading: Push Notification Throughput and Error Checking
on https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG44 -