# APNS Apple Push Notification token goes stale and stops working

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Does anyone know what could cause a Apple Push Notification token to go stale?  After some time the Push token no longer works for a given device, while other tokens work.  If I delete that account for that device and create a new account for that device and receive a new Push token from Apple, then the new Push token works fine.

**Edit 1 - This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819315/max-number-of-devices-to-send-to-apns-socket-sever) claims that push notification connections fail after 200 notifications and the  connection has to be restarted.  Has anyone else had this experience?**

Could the Push token go stale because Apple saw the Push connection for that device being brought up and down too often in a given period of time?  If so, is there some way to programmatically know when a Push token has gone stale?

Answer (score 0):

Your application should register for push notifications every time it is launched. This way you will get the current device token every time it is launched, and if it changes (you can store the old copy in the app in order to know that), you can send it to your server.

You can see a related answer with quotes from the APNS guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15235472/767730).

Comment: I do store the current push notification token on the website every time the app is launched.  But the push notifications stop working for one device, and it is usually a device I've been using a lot.  This makes me think that Apple has stopped that push token from working because of some usage violation.  Just not sure what that violation is and how to determine programmatically that the violation has occurred.

Comment: How many messages until you hit the limit, and is your app in the foreground or the background? Perhaps Apple caps the background notification rate per (device,app) combination.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how many messages I've sent before I hit the limit but it could easily be 200.  I'm doing a lot of testing on one device and I send about 5 messages per test, so it could very well be that I am hitting the 200 message limit.